# PHP - sorting arrays based on a file

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting

i am new at PHP and I need some help with sorting arrays based on a files. My code causes the array to have a separate sort - it sorts the contents of the first file first and then the second file.

```
$file1=@fopen("first.txt","r");
$file2=@fopen("second.txt","r");
while(!feof($file1) && !feof($file2))
{$tab[]=@fgets($file1);$tab[]=@fgets($file2);}
@fclose($file1);
@fclose($file2);

$opening=@fopen("prime.txt","w");
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($tab);$i++){sort($tab);@fwrite($opening,($tab[$i]."\n"));};
```

I don't know how to sort an array of two files.

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: I didn't give up and I did it luckily.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I see the error in your code, other than you only need to `sort` once.  But you can just read into arrays, merge them and then sort:

```
$tab = array_merge(file("first.txt"), file("second.txt"));
sort($tab);
file_put_contents("prime.txt", $tab);
```

If it's still not sorting the way you think it should, then the data is not what you think it is.  Maybe all lines in `first.txt` start with a space or invisible character, but not the lines in `second.txt`.  Or something similar.